# How to initialize WebClient using object initializers?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `WebClient` like this:

```
WebClient _webClient = new WebClient
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,               
};
_webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
```

I want to initialize the `Headers` using an object initializer:

```
WebClient _webClient = new WebClient
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    Headers = new WebHeaderCollection
    {
        "user-agent",
        "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)",
    }
};
```

But I don't know how to write that. Is it possible?

**Update 2016/07/07**

It's about [indexer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexer) and [Object and Collection Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx). In a normal collection e.g `List<int> numbers`
you can init by following code

```
    List<int> numers = new List<int> {
        1, 2, 3
    };
```

But `WebHeaderCollectio` which name header we want to initailze is not `List<...>` just a generic property in `WebClient`

```
public class WebClient : Component
{
    ...
    public WebHeaderCollection Headers { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

[Object and Collection Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) mentions **Collection initializers let you specify one or more element initializers when you initialize a collection class that implements IEnumerable or a class with an Add extension method.**

So let we check the `WebHeaderCollection` class

```
public class WebHeaderCollection : NameValueCollection, ISerializable
{
    public string this[HttpResponseHeader header] { get; set; }

    public string this[HttpRequestHeader header] { get; set; }

    public void Add(string header);

    public void Add(HttpRequestHeader header, string value);

    public void Add(HttpResponseHeader header, string value);
}

WebHeaderCollection : NameValueCollection : NameObjectCollectionBase : IEnumerable
```

And finally there is a my practice sample

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PeopleEnumerable peopleEnumerable = new PeopleEnumerable {
                { "Michael", "1" },
                { "Mike", "2" },
                { "Butters;3" },
            };

            Console.WriteLine(peopleEnumerable["1"]);
            Console.WriteLine(peopleEnumerable["2"]);
            Console.WriteLine(peopleEnumerable["3"]);
        }
    }

    public class PeopleEnumerable : IEnumerable
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> _peopels = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public string this[string id]
        {
            get
            {
                return _peopels[id];
            }
            set
            {
                _peopels[id] = value;
            }
        }

        public void Add(string name, string id)
        {
            _peopels.Add(id, name);
        }
        public void Add(string nameAndId)
        {
            var name = nameAndId.Split(';')[0];
            var id = nameAndId.Split(';')[1];

            _peopels.Add(id, name);
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

You need to implement IEnumerable or you will get **Cannot initialize type 'PeopleEnumerable' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'**

Comment: Did you try that? Are you getting any exception?

Comment: Yes, I tried. This is the exception message:
{"Specified value does not have a ':' separator.\r\nParameter name: header"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this. You have to split the property and its value by a colon (`:`):

```
WebClient _webClient = new WebClient
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true,
        Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
        Headers = new WebHeaderCollection
        {
            "user-agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)"
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you  It's work now, but could you explain why?

Comment: Because the `WebHeaderCollection` takes just one variable using the object initializer. You have to split it like you would normally do in a HTTP request. You actually tried to create two headers. That is why it failed.

Comment: So use ":" to spilit is just defined by WebHeaderCollection?

Comment: Indeed. It calls [this `Add` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/965xw3x5(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can also do it like this (without the `:` in the header):

```
private static WebClient _doClient = new WebClient
{
    BaseAddress = "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/domains/example.com/",
    Headers = new WebHeaderCollection { { "Authorization", "Bearer " + _digitalOceanApiKey } }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. It's work too. But I don't know why maybe I will ask another question.

Comment: @MichaelMao `WebClient.Headers` has an `.Add` method that accepts 2 args -- I'm basically using that one.

Comment: Could you explain why you can initialize the header in constructor?

Comment: @MichaelMao They're called "object initializers". Read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx#Anchor_2).

Comment: But I didn't see anything about add method in your link. I know we need to implement the add method so we can use this kind initialize but I don't know the reason.

Comment: @MichaelMao I'm having trouble finding where that's actually documented...but basically each item inside `Headers = new WebHeaderCollection { ... }` is passed to `WebHeaderCollection.Add`. From [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y280s7kx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) we can see that `.Add` supports 2 args, so we each element can be a `{list}` with 2 more elements, which are passed as each arg.

Comment: I will try try to figure out the reason and share with you :D

Comment: I have a sample. And I think compiler do the thing for us.